# How to get the remaining data in DB after Limit

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 users in my database I want to get the first 3 data and send them a specific email. How can I get the remaining 2 users and sent them on another set of email

```
$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 3');
$sql->execute();
while($result = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     mail sending codes...
}
```

DB: Users

```
id | Name | Email
1  | John | john@gmail.com 
2  | Mark | mark@gmail.com 
3  | Erik | erik@gmail.com 
4  | Ryan | ryan@gmail.com 
5  | Grey | grey@gmail.com
```

Comment: You can use the SQL word OFFSET can't you ? "SELECT * FROM Users OFFSET 3"

Answer (score 0):

the first 3

```
SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 3
```

the next 2 users

```
SELECT * FROM Users OFFSET 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](https://www.essentialsql.com/using-offset-and-fetch-with-the-order-by-clause/) about `OFFSET`

```
SELECT Email FROM Users OFFSET 3
```

`OFFSET` skips a specific number (in this case 3) of rows.